# How can I use a ui bootstrap directive within a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the uib-carousel directive within my costum directive. The images for test are rendering with ng-repeat but no carousel component is present. 
The uib-carousel and uib-slide attributes are ignored, why ?
I did not injected the ui.bootstrap module because it should be done by grunt in my case, if I try to inject it anyway it gives me an injection error.
I am using grunt to run the client.

**This is  my example module :**

```
<div ng-controller="LifeCarouselExampleController as vm">
<life-carousel interval="vm.interval" images="vm.images">
</life-carousel>
```

```
angular.module('cgm.life.components.lifeCarousel.example', ['cgm.life.components.lifeCarousel'])
    .controller('LifeCarouselExampleController', LifeCarouselExampleController);

function LifeCarouselExampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.images = ['src/toolbox/components/lifeCarousel/example/img/stomato1.jpg', 'src/toolbox/components/lifeCarousel/example/img/stomato2.jpg', 'src/toolbox/components/lifeCarousel/example/img/stomato3.jpg'];
    vm.interval = 4;
}
```

**And this is my custom directive module:**

```
angular
    .module('cgm.life.components.lifeCarousel', [])
    .directive('lifeCarousel', LifeCarouselFactory);

//lifeCarousel.$inject = ['$timeout', 'screenSizeService', '$rootScope'];

/* @ngInject */
//LifeCarouselFactory.$inject = ['$compile'];
function LifeCarouselFactory() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
       // require: 'ngModel',
        //transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'life_Carousel.html',
        scope: {
            interval: '=',
            images: '='
        },
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope) {
        var Carousel = {
            setSlides: function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.images.length; i++) {
                    var slide =
                    {
                        image: scope.images[i], text: 'img_' + i, id: i
                    };
                    scope.slides.push(slide);
                }
            }
        };
        scope.slides = [];
        Carousel.setSlides();
        scope.carouselId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000000000) + 1);
        scope.noWrapSlides = false;
        scope.active = 0;
    }

}
```

**And template of custom directive:**

```
<div style="width:75%; margin-left: 11.5%">
<div uib-carousel id="{{carouselId}}" active="{{active}}" interval="{{interval}}" noWrapSlides="{{noWrapSlides}}"
              style="max-width: 80%; margin-left: 10%">
    <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="$index">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="max-height: 400px; min-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you inspect the source to check if grunt is actually injecting ui.bootstrap? when you run the application? It could be something related to grunt.

Comment: Yes I checked, and everything seems ok.. grunt injects the ui.bootstrap that contains also ui.bootstrap.carousel. The strange thing is that when I try to inject the ui.bootstrap.carousel into my example it gives me an module injection error and I don't know why.

Comment: If for example I inject ui.bootstrap.collapse, everything is ok .

Comment: Seems like only when I am trying to inject the ui.bootstrap.carousel I am facing the moduler injection error .. That is strange.

Comment: By the way I am using ui bootstrap Version: 1.3.3

Comment: By injecting do you mean including the script tag right? You can also check the order of the files ui bootstrap should be added before your own code.

Comment: By injecting I mean doing something like this : .module('components.lifeCarousel', ['ui.bootstrap.carousel']);